# pfSense Site-to-Site routes

Tags: routing, vpn, pfsense

I was presented with an issue regarding an actual setup using pfSense at two locations.

pfSense Site A is the OpenVPN Server and B is the client.

Everything works, the LAN on Site A can communicate with LAN on site B and also the other way around.

Site A LAN GW IP is 192.168.10.254
Site B LAN GW IP is 192.168.5.1

Issue is that some specific hosts on Site A should use Internet Breakout at site B but as they have the 192.168.10.254 as GW automatically get to the Internet through Site A WAN.

I would like to achieve is having Site A hosts going to Internet through Site B WAN instead of A.

I've tried to set the default GW on site A Host (eg. 192.168.10.33) as 192.168.5.1, but of course it has no routes for that.

I'm sorry if some information is missing, but not really a network guy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be easier if Site B were the server and Site A were the OVPN client.  Provide Site A (via the OVPN server config) with the subnet and gateway available on the other end of the tunnel and see how things go.

Then if Site A host 192.168.10.33 has a default route that travels across 192.168.10.254 (which has a IP provided via OVPN of 192.168.5.2, let's say) and a next hop of 192.168.5.1 and then a WAN IP of {some.public.ip.here} then that makes perfect sense to me.

You may need to use a firewall rule to direct 192.168.10.33 traffic to an alternate gateway under the Advanced firewall rule settings.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. I can't change the network setup. Maybe change the type of site to site VPN tunnel? Or no other way you can remenber?

Comment: The challenge is that even if you can point the traffic relating to 192.168.10.33 to Site B towards Site A the priority of the routers is against you.  The OpenVPN server/client kind of sets that.

Comment: This will double your work but if everything is routable it should still be possible to use firewall rules to redirect traffic to the non-default gw and then to the internet gw and to port forwarding.  It is not the simplest solution and simplest will usually give you best results.  Check out the pfsense forums, too, for recommendations.  They/We are a friendly bunch!

Comment: I've changed the topology after some discussion, now Site A is the Client and B is the server. Still can't figure out how to route from that specific host to the other GW.